# How to emulate a SATA disk drive in QEMU

Tags: qemu, device-emulation, sata

I want to emulate a SATA disk drive in QEMU to check a device driver I'm trying to develop. How can this be done? Would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 15):

The [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU/Options#Hard_drive) offers these parameters:

```
-drive id=disk,file=IMAGE.img,if=none \
-device ahci,id=ahci \
-device ide-hd,drive=disk,bus=ahci.0
```

> Set emulation layer for an ICH-9 AHCI controller <s>(not yet stable )</s> and use the specified image file for it. The AHCI emulation supports NCQ, so multiple read or write requests can be outstanding at the same time.

EDIT: A revision to the Wiki on [31 October 2018](https://wiki.gentoo.org/index.php?title=QEMU%2FOptions&type=revision&diff=744864&oldid=623918) suggests the AHCI controller may be stable now.

Comment: Is the drive auto-mounted at boot? Or do you have to manually mount the drive once Qemu has booted Linux?

Comment: For me a device was automatically created but drive was not mounted. It will be visible with `lsblk`, you will need to format it (to ext4 for example) and mount it (normally to `/mnt/data`). This was useful for me https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-partition-and-format-storage-devices-in-linux

Comment: `ide-drive` is deprecated, use `ide-hd` instead, got `'ide-drive' is not a valid device model name` and found no explanation. [some details](https://github.com/ASoft-se/Gentoo-HAI/issues/57)

Comment: @NiKiZe thanks, I see you've also edited the Gentoo Wiki page also.  I've updated the command to match your change.

Answer (score 3):

When using i386 or x86_64 with Q35 machine type(-M q35), IDE disk has been AHCI by default.